# Is the modern Indian state Tripura somehow related to the three cities Shiva destroyed in his Tripurantaka form?

Tags: shiva, bala-tripura-sundari

**Please read Edit 1(At the end)**

Does the state, Tripura, derive its name from the Three legendary asura cities which Lord Shiva destroyed in his Tripurantaka form?

Most searches return that the name is based off of the 'Tripura Sundari', but a quick wikipedia search shows that Tripura Sundari is herself probably related to the three cities:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripura_Sundari#:~:text=Tripura%20Sundari%20is%20also%20known,Three%20Cities%2C%22%20or%20Tripurasundari.
>
> > > Tripura Sundari is also known by names as Ṣoḍaśī ("She who is the sixteenth"[12]), Lalitā, Kāmeśvarī, Śrīvidyā and Raj Rajeshwari.[1] The Shodashi Tantra refers to Shodashi as the "Beauty of the Three Cities," or Tripurasundari.[13]

So does Tripura have any relation to the three cities? If so, what?

*****EDIT 1***: I mean to ask: Like Shri Ram is said to have been born in the city of Ayodhya, which is present in modern India, and does have references to his place of birth etc. Similarly, is the modern Indian state *Tripura* somehow related to the three cities Shiva destroyed in his Tripurantaka form? And if so, is the place where the event happened mentioned, or are there legends in the state regarding this ancient happening?**

Comment: Tripura might mean 3 cities or 3 worlds..in which context u want to know: Tripurasundari or Tripurantaka? If Tripurantaka then, yes these 3 cities were built by 3 Ashura brothers which were later destroyed by Shiva that's how he came to be known as Tripurarai or Tripurantaka..

Comment: duplicate question

Comment: @YDS Thanks for the comment, I guess I wasn't clear enough, please read the new edit :)

Comment: Tripura is the Saskritisied version of the Kokborok(the language spoken by the native tribals of that area)  word Twipra. The state has nothing to do with the anecdote of Tripura mentioned in Shiva Purana.

Comment: all 3 cities were not on earth - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226142.html Also, [Tripura States Of Our Union by Phanibhushan Acharjya](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.489119/page/n14/mode/1up) says that it's derived from some king Tripur or Lord Tripurarai (Shiva) was worshiped by people of this region..but this Q looks more suitable to History..